# Javascript dom parsing troubleshoot

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dom, jqgrid

I create button from the string and add it to the DOM.

Here is javascript code :

```
var se = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default btn-quick' title='Save Row' onclick=\"jQuery('#jqgrid').saveRow('" + cl + "','" + null + "','" + '../UpdateStatus' + "','" + {'name':"content1"} + "','" + null + "','" + null + "','" + null + "');\"><i class='fa fa-save'></i></button>";
```

Here is how button attached to the DOM:

```
 jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[0], { act: se });
```

jqgrid - is `id` of some html element.

As you can see inside button I have `onClick` attribute that calls function named `saveRow`.

Here is the signature of the called function:

```
saveRow: function (rowid, successfunc, url, extraparam, aftersavefunc, errorfunc, afterrestorefunc) {}
```

One of the parameters that I pass to the `saveRow` function is json:

```
{'name':"content1"}
```

And her how the button looks in the DOM tree after page is loaded:

[image]
(sorry for small text)

As you can see DOM converted this parameter(in red frame):

```
{'name':"content1"}
```

to this:

```
'[Object object]'
```

Any idea why the JSON parameter converted to this `[Object object]`?

**UPDATE:**

Here how DOM is looks:

[image]

If I use this attitude:

```
se = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default btn-quick' title='Save Row' onclick=\"jQuery('#jqgrid').saveRow('" + cl + "','" + null + "','" + '../UpdateStatus' + "','" + JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar' }) + "','" + null + "','" + null + "','" + null + "');\"><i class='fa fa-save'></i></button>";
```

**UPDATE2:**

Here how DOM is looks:

[image]

If I use this attitude:

```
se="<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default btn-quick' title='Save Row' onclick='jQuery('#jqgrid').saveRow('" + cl + "','" + null + "','" + '../UpdateStatus' + "','" + JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar' }) + "','" + null + "','" + null + "','" + null + "');'><i class='fa fa-save'></i></button>";
```

After the button is clicked I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you trying to add JSON as html it call the function `toString()` which return `[Object object]` like in this example.

```js
var obj = {foo: 'bar'};

console.log(obj.toString());
```

> By default, the toString() method is inherited by every object descended from Object. If this method is not overridden in a custom object, toString() returns "[object type]", where type is the object type.

<sub>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)</sub>

If you want to use your JSON convert it first to string using [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

> The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string

Like this:

```js
var obj = {foo: 'bar'};

var a = "<a onclick='doSome(" + JSON.stringify(obj) + ")'>Do Something</a>";

document.body.innerHTML += a;

function doSome(obj) {
  console.log(obj.foo);
}
```

**Update 2**

```js
var cl = 198;

var se = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default btn-quick' title='Save Row' onclick='jQuery(\"#jqgrid\").saveRow(\"" + cl + "\", " + null + "," + "\"../UpdateStatus\"," + JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar' }) + ")'><i class='fa fa-save'></i></button>";

document.body.innerHTML += se;

jQuery.fn.saveRow = function() {
  console.log(arguments);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for post Mosh! I tryed this way:
onclick=\"jQuery('#jqgrid').saveRow('" + cl + "','" + null + "','" + '../UpdateStatus' + "','" + JSON.stringify({'name':"content1"})  + "','" + null + "','" + null + "','" + null + "')
But still I didng get desired result. :(

Comment: Do you have a public URL so I could debug it? (Or can you create [bin](http://jsbin.com) or something?) What exactly the result? Keep attention to the using of single (`'`) or double (`"`) quotation(s), it's important. Can you post an image with the HTML result?

Comment: Mosh,  I tryed to make fiddler but it's not works properly.Please see update above.

Comment: Like I told you, you have to use a single quotation in the `onclick` attribute (just like you did in the rest attributes. `onclick='jQuery('#jqgrid').saveRow('" + cl + "','" + null + "','" + '../UpdateStatus' + "','" + JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar' }) + "','" + null + "','" + null + "','" + null + "');'>`

Comment: Mosh tnx I just pasted onclick='..'  above that you wrote then checked the DOM tree  and ... voila it's worked!!!But after It when I click the saveRow() method not fired and  I noticed that error: 

 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }     tables-jqgrid.html:2

Comment: Can you post the output again?

Comment: Check my update.. I didn't do for all arguments, just an example. You should pay attention very carefully about the position and the use of the characters (`'`, `"`. `\"` etc.)